# ftp: transfer parts of a file?

Tags: mysql, file-transfer, ftp

If I'm transferring a 2GB sql file with filezilla, and it timed out after 50%. In my server, I can see that the new transferred file is about 1.1GB.

I want to know if there's a way through the same method (filezilla : ftp/sftp), to transfer the remaining .9GB without re-transferring the whole file again?

Comment: What are you using as your FTP server?  ProFTP? PureFTP?

Answer (score 1):

Filezilla has a "resume" option

Answer (score 0):

rsync+ssh can take care of that for you:

```
rsync --partial --progress user@host:/path/to/file <local file>
```